# Rails application on shared hosting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shared-hosting, shared

Is there a way that I can deploy my locally made rails app on a shared host that has Ruby installed?

Comment: Do you want a hosting provider that supports Rails? Or do you want to know how to install the app on your provider?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't provide enough backstory, the person the application is for already has hosting. So I guess it would be how to install it.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would use [Capistrano](https://capistranorb.com/). There are plenty of books and tutorials around that will tell you how to use it to deploy Rails applications. It is very easy to configure.

Comment: Just a heads up, this link is broken, it leads to a random news page.

Comment: @Jake Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Capistrano to deploy and (Mongrel or Passenger... preferably the latter... or if you HAVE to, FastCGI although FastCGI is pretty slow with Rails) to serve.

If you have a shared host you'll have to vendor your Rails version and all your gems, as you probably won't have access to install gems. Even if you did, you won't want Rails picking old versions of things.

Answer (score 1):

[Dreamhost](http://www.dreamhost.com) supports Rails, many others probably do also.

As for installation of your app: it depends a bit on what's already available on your shared host, and what you're allow to do / install / configure there. For Dreamhost, [here's their documentation](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Rails). Other shared hosting solutions may or may not be similar depending on their policy.

Comment: I think that @Vector isn' asking about "what shared hosting I can use?" but if he can deploy on a shared hosting that has ruby installed (probably there is no rails and other important stuff there).

Comment: Just want to know if I can have multiple rails apps for multiple subdomains on dreamhost?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found is to install the `passenger` gem. Once you've uploaded your app to your account all you need to do is add a few lines to your `.htaccess` file and you should be off.

Comment: Do you have a link on how to set this up or a how to?

Comment: The only info I have to hand is for my host (Site5) but it should be similar. http://www.site5.com/blog/programming/ruby-rails/how-to-deploy-phusion-passenger-to-a-subdirectory-routing-errors-and-restarting/20090414/

Answer (score 0):

Definitely capistrano + git (git, if you have SSH access, like f.e. in HostingRails shared host), nothing can be easier.

Neat Capistrano guide: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10100

How to config Capistrano + git: http://github.com/guides/deploying-with-capistrano

Some nice Capistrano recipes: http://github.com/josh/slicehost

Answer (score 0):

1. Assuming your http server is nginx or apache, install [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com)
2. On the Passenger site, there are very good docs for configuring Apache/nginx with Rails
3. As a first step, just copy your Rails app somewhere to the host and get Passenger working
4. Once you have that working, you will need a better way to deploy/update the app; as others have suggested, Capistrano is a popular way to do it and you should have no problem finding some tutorials online to help you do it

I have done steps 1-3 and it is incredibly easy and works perfectly fine (I was just too lazy to do step 4).

Answer (score 0):

Found a good reference : [REFERENCE LINK](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/how-do-i-start-using-ruby-on-rails) this will help to deploy ROR App on a shared host.